# How to change default dynamic library search path for libasan

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, address-sanitizer

I have an application that is supposed to run on various platforms i.e. ARM, i386, amd64 etc. I want to check any possible memory leaks, I have address sanitizer enabled in GCC as
`-fsanitize=address`
We are using buildroot to compile the whole OS+Application. To ensure that each developer has same versions of library installed, we pack all the required dynamic libraries in `ProjectX/lib`
path and set this as LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
All works fine if address sanitizer is switched off. On compiling with address-sanitizer and running the app gives

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required   by BUILD/host_shared_0_1/host/usr/i686-buildroot-linux-gnu/lib/libasan.so.1)
```

`GLIBC_2.23' is already there but packed under $ProjectX/lib
However, libasan looks for it under /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ and on finding an incompatible version, throws the error.

QS: How can I instruct libasan to look for the required libraries in the path specified by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your buildroot and actual runtime environment are binary incompatible i.e. libasan requires libm version *newer* than the one installed in environment. It's not Asan's problem per se, binary incompatibility may cause issues for the rest of your software as well. For details, google for "version GLIBC_2.23 not found".

> How can I instruct libasan to look for the required libraries in the path
>   specified by LD_LIBRARY_PATH only.

That's what it does now.

Comment: So you mean to say that if I have GLIBC_2.17 installed and I compile a program using GLIBC_2.24, it is still binary incompatible even if I provide GLIBC_2.24 in dynamic library path ?

I want to look at GLIBC as boost or openCV library. Regardless of which version I may have installed locally, as long as I provide the right versions in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, binaries always work !

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: > So you mean to say that if I have GLIBC_2.17 installed and I compile a program using GLIBC_2.24, it is still binary incompatible even if I provide GLIBC_2.24 in dynamic library path?

Comment: "it is still binary incompatible even if I provide GLIBC_2.24 in dynamic library path" - this should work if GLIBC_2.24-enabled libc.so precedes old, GLIBC-2.17 libc.so in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But in your case it seems that libm.so.6 is either missing in ProjectX/lib or path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH is incorrect because dynamic linker fails to find GLIBC_2.24 version and instead loads old incompatible /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6.